# How to separate bots and real users, then only send messages to real users?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@commands.command(name="message",
                description="Send message all the members",
                pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@commands.bot_has_permissions(administrator=True)          
async def msg(self, ctx, *, args=None):
    if args != None:
        members = ctx.guild.members
        for member in members:
            if member is member.bot:
                continue
            print('A BOT')
            if member is not member.bot:
                try:
                    await member.send(args + "  " + (f"\n{member.mention}"))
                    await ctx.send("Message Sent to : " + member.name)  
                except:
                    await ctx.send("Message couldn't send to : " + member.name)

                
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send('Pls provide a massage')
```

I just want to send a message to all members of the server where the bot will be skipped. Thanks!

Comment: Ideally you should be pinging everyone or a role that was setup for notifications instead of attempting to DM everyone. To some extent that could be considered API abuse and based on the number of users could take a while due to ratelimits. Additionally, users could have DMs disabled which will cause an error when attempting to send them a message.

Comment: Oops I got the point! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`member is member.bot` is checking that the `member` object **is** the `member.bot` object - which will *never* be True.

You just need:

```py
if member.bot:
    continue
```

[`member.bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.bot) attribute will be `True` if it's a bot and `False` if it's not. Therefore, we only need to check for that.

Perhaps look up Python operators and consider a beginner course / tutorial to understand the language and it's syntax.